Do we plug in the old values or the new values during the gradient descent update?
I have a scenario when I am trying to optimize a vector of D dimensions. Every component of the vector is dependent on other components according to a function such as:
summation over (i,j):
(1-e(x_i)(x_j))/2
where e is constant and x are embeddings of i and j
Lets say the update rule is be:
x_i=x_i-lr0.5(e)(x_j)
where lr is the learning rate. Do we use old value of x_j or the updated value? What I mean is x_j might get a new embedding during the update and x_i in the same iteration might get updated too.

this question might get better answers on Cross Validated or AI Stack Exchange

ok thanks, i am worried I didn't express the question right and it might be hard to understand. I tried my best...
